# насколько безопасно устанавливать расширения в лагаси режиме?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm

Мне нужен графический пакет для рисования графиков. Я использую версию react 18. Когда я устанавливаю, он говорит, что мне нужна версия 17 для этого пакета.

могу ли я установить этот пакет в legacy режиме? насколько это будет влиять на безопасность проекта? или лучше использовать другое расширение для графиков которое поддерживает react 18?

```
npm i legacy peer deps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установка пакета в legacy режиме с помощью npm i <package_name>@legacy --save-peer-deps может помочь установить пакет с низкой версией зависимости, но это может привести к проблемам с безопасностью и стабильностью в дальнейшем, потому что вы используете устаревшую версию пакета. Рекомендуется искать другой пакет для графиков, который поддерживает React 18, так как это может быть более безопасным и стабильным решением. Пакеты такие как recharts, victory, react-vis и plotly.js-react поддерживают React 18 и могут быть хорошим выбором для создания графиков в вашем проекте. Стоит произвести сравнительный анализ функциональности и возможностей каждого из них и выбрать наиболее подходящий для вашего проекта.